# Is it possible to extract data from Google Tag Manager without using datalayer?

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I have this piece of code on my site:

```
 <div class="product-cta">
                            <span class="price">2.998,-</span>
                        <div class="btn-wrapper">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-addtocart btn-xlarge" href="#" data-basket-url="/kassen/kurv/" data-product-id="25984"><i class="icon icon-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
```

Is it possible to extract the numbers that come after data-product-id= to Google Tag Manager without pushing it through datalayer, only using what is in the existing code? This is on a product page and is to be used with the Facebook Pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try couple methods without pushing it to the dataLayer. You could use JS (natively or jQuery) to scrape that info, or you could also use a built-in auto-event variable like this:

[image]

If you want to use the AEV, then you would likely be capturing that data on a click or something as the AEVs are "essentially [macros] that can be used to refer to, for example, the DOM element where a click occurred" (cf. https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/auto-event-tracking-google-tag-manager/).